# Cannot Add PgAdmin New Connection on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin

After install pgAdmin III from Ubuntu Software Center, I opened it and it required to add a connection to a server. So I filled in information as below:

[image: Adding connection to local server]

Upon clicking on Ok Button, it showed the error message

> Error connecting to the server: could not translate host name
>   "http://127.0.0.1" to address: Name or service not known

As message indicated, I thought the postgres service was not started. Therefore, I went on go terminal console and start service by entering `sudo service postgresql start`, but it returned `Failed to start postgresql.service: Unit postgresql.service failed to load: No such file or directory.`
. What's wrong or missing for my pgAdmin III? I'm just using Ubuntu earlier and I have never this problem on windows. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http://127.0.0.1` is more a URL, that field is looking for a host so simply remove the `http://` to leave the localhost's IP address **`127.0.0.1`** or type `localhost` if that resolves to the correct address (it should, usually, via `/etc/hosts` or the like)

Also, Debian/Ubuntu tend to ship the database servers separately. For Ubuntu, the `postgresql` package (which requires `postgresql-common`) package should include `/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service` therefore you should be able to **`sudo systemctl start postgresql`**

**Do you have [postgresql](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/postgresql) (as opposed to postgresql-client) installed?**

Comment: Thanks, I guess `postgresql` was not installed. I changed host name and tried your suggested command `sudo systemctl start postgresql` but the same error as above `no such file or directory`. I tried `sudo apt-get install postgresql-common` as you mentioned but still error `The following packages have unmet dependencies: postgresql-common : Breaks: logrotate (>= 3.8) but 3.8.7-2ubuntu2 is to be installed. E: Unabled to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` What should I do to correct this. Thanks.

Comment: Try `sudo aptitude install <packagename>`

Aptitude will give up less easily, and will attempt to find solutions which may involve modifying other packages. It may give you more explanation of the problem and options for fixing it.[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: By ‘requires’ I mean not that they need to be installed first, but that installing `postgresql` should also pull `postgres-9.6` (or more recent version) which in turn pulls in `postgresql-common`… by installing the postgresql meta-package, you get them all and as soon as you uninstall postgresql those will also be removed, provided nothing else depends on them.

Comment: Thanks. I tried `sudo aptitude install postgresql-common` but it came up with error command not found `sudo: aptitude: command not found`.

Comment: Okay that means the program is not installed, try installing it with something like `sudo apt-get install aptitude`.  A further thought is that your machine is not aware of recent packages just updated, `sudo apt-get update` will make sure your machine is up-to-date with what is available via Ubuntu's repositories (and any other repos your machine is configured to look into).

Comment: Thanks. I run command `sudo apt-get update` complete `Reading package lists... Done`. Then I install aptitude `sudo apt-get install aptitude`. It returned message `Depends: libcwidget3 but it is not going to be installed`, `Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.0.2) but it is not going to be installed`, `Depends: libxapian22 but it is not going to be installed`, `Recommends: apt-xapian-index but it is not going to be installed`. `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: does `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` show any held packages? If none held will just return to shell without output.

Comment: `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` did not return anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157847/discussion-between-andrew-siplas-and-houy-narun).